# Software for front end Web development

Tags: javascript, web-development, css, html-editor

Currently I am using CodePen.io but I want to move to a downloadable program is it is more professional and doesn't require internet.

The code I mainly use is HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and some JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WebStorm**](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is a professional IDE for web authoring of JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.

From their web site:

> Enjoy code completion, powerful navigation features, on-the-fly error detection, and refactorings.
>
> Modern frameworks
>
> WebStorm provides advanced coding assistance for Angular, React and Meteor. Enjoy support for PhoneGap, Cordova and Ionic for mobile development and develop for server-side with Node.js. All in one IDE!
>
> Smart editor
>
> The IDE analyzes your project to provide the best code completion results for all supported languages. Hundreds of built-in inspections report any possible issues right as you type and suggest quick-fix options.
>
> Navigation & Search
>
> WebStorm helps you get around your code more efficiently and save time when working with large projects. Jump to a method, function or variable definition in just one click, or search for the usage.
>
> Debugging, tracing and testing
>
> WebStorm provides powerful built-in tools for debugging, testing and tracing your client-side and Node.js applications. With minimum configuration required and thoughtful integration into the IDE, there tasks are much easier with WebStorm.
>
> Debugging
>
> WebStorm provides a built-in debugger for your client-side code (that works with Chrome) and Node.js apps. Place the breakpoints, step through the code, and evaluate expressions – all without leaving the IDE.
>
> Unit testing
>
> Perform unit testing with ease, as WebStorm integrates with Karma test runner and Mocha. Run and debug tests right inside the IDE, view results in a nice and visual format, and navigate to the test code.
>
> Tracing and profiling
>
> WebStorm features spy-js, a built-in tool that helps you trace your JavaScript code. Explore how files are connected with function calls and efficiently identify any possible bottlenecks.
>
> Seamless tool integration
>
> WebStorm integrates with popular command line tools for web development, providing you with a productive, streamlined development experience without using the command line.
>
> Build tools
>
> Enjoy a simple unified UI for running Grunt, Gulp or npm tasks right from the IDE. All tasks are listed in a special tool window, so simply double-click on the task name to start it.
>
> Code quality tools
>
> In addition to hundreds of WebStorm’s own inspections, it can run JSHint, ESLint, JSCS or JSLint against your code and highlight any issues on the fly, right in the editor.
>
> Project templates
>
> Start new projects from the Welcome screen using popular project templates like Express or Web starter kit, and access even more project generator thanks to integration with Yeoman.
>
> IDE features
>
> WebStorm is built on top of the open-source IntelliJ Platform, which we at JetBrains have been developing and perfecting for over 15 years. Enjoy the fine-tuned, yet highly customizable experience it provides to fit your development workflow.
>
> VCS
>
> WebStorm provides a unified UI for working with many popular Version Control Systems, ensuring a consistent user experience across git, GitHub, SVN, Mercurial, and Perforce.
>
> Local history
>
> Whether you’re using VCS or not, Local history can be a real code saver. At any time you can inspect the history of either a particular file or directory, and roll back to any of its previous versions.
>
> Customization
>
> WebStorm is extremely customizable. Adjust it to perfectly suit your coding style, from shortcuts, fonts and visual themes to tool windows and editor layout.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike WebStorm, [**CudaText**](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor is lite, but it supports major front-end languages (JS, CSS, PHP, JSX, LESS, SCSS, Stylus etc), and has many plugins for front-end. Free, cross-platform.

It is analog of **Sublime Text** editor.